# Copy a range of rows with identity column change SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database

This sounds weird, but I need to copy a range of rows from a table in my database into the same table by changing a couple of values.

My main issue would be with the `identity` column. They want the identity of those rows to start at a specific number but entering data through the app should not change the **normal order**.

Basically:

- Copy rows 100-190 to rows 1-90
- Next entry should be 191

I there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBCC CHECKIDENT can force the current identity value. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('schema.table', RESEED, 190);
```